# Nuxt and router.js: How to add router.beforeEach() guards?

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router

I am using a `router.js` file (from `@nuxtjs/router` module) to handle my routes instead of Nuxt's `pages` directory structure.

How/Where would I add the following code in the `router.js` file?

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(x => x.meta.requiresAuth)
  const currentUser = auth.currentUser
  // If the route requires authentication, and the user is not signed-in, then redirect the user to the Login view to enter their credentials, and sign-in to the app before visiting the route.
  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('/login')
...snip..
```

My current `router.js` structure is like so:

```
..snip..
Vue.use(Router)

export function createRouter() {
  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
      ...snip..
    ]
  })
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: NOt sure if this is optimal solution, but I injected the beforeEach code via `plugins/route.js` and then added that to the nuxt.config.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most "Nuxt" way to do this is using middleware.  Here's an example from those docs, using a named middleware:

```
// inside /middleware/authenticated.js

export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  // remember to import "auth"!
  const currentUser = auth.currentUser
  if (!currentUser) return redirect('/login')
}
```

Then, inside each page you'd like to protect, you may do the following:

```
<template>
  <h1>Secret page</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    middleware: 'authenticated'
  }
</script>
```

Just remember, your middleware name in your component must match the name of the file in your middleware directory!

Comment: thanks very much! Will give this a look and mark your answer once I test it out.

Comment: thanks again. This makes total sense and I am excited to put this in practice.